# Hover only works when user clicks on the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Following is the link to my js fiddle in which i am trying to show a popover on hover property of the element `hover for popover` with id `a1` . The problem i am facing is that when the page loads for the first time and on hover on that element the popover doesnot display. But when user clicks on `hover for popover` and then do the hover,  then `hover` property works perfectly fine kindly let me know why isn't it happening on the page load event and how can i fix it so user doesnot have to click on the  button and it display whatever in it.

**Note:** It can be easily done by following but the problem is ids for the elements are being dynamically generated so i cannot use the following method for specifically one id.

```
$(function ()
{ $("#example").popover();
});
```

**JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/weuWk/323/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add a class to all of your hover elements:

```
<span id="a1" class="btn large primary hoverable">Popover</span>
```

Then, add the popover to each item:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hoverable').popover({title: "Hello"});
});
```

**Edit:** To reference the `id` (or any other attribute), you can use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hoverable').each(function(){
      $(this).popover({title: $(this).attr('id')});
    });
});
```

Comment: this is actually better then my answer :)

Comment: okay one last question what if on click event i have to pass the id to popover on that id what should be my function in that case??

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem comes from the fact you are calling the `popover()` function before your document is properly loaded and then before `$('#a1')` in your example can match anything.

Check your updated jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/weuWk/325/
You need to call popover only when your document is ready like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#a1').popover({title: "Hello"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed http://jsfiddle.net/pieterwillaert/weuWk/327/

what you do is the following:

- when the document is loaded you iterate through all your buttons (I did it by using `'span'` you could easely change that too `'.button'`)
- you give each button a popover

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {

      $('span').each(function(index) {
           $(this).popover({title: "Hello"});
      });

  });​
  ```